# Permission denied while installing .Net sdk on Ubuntu with dotnet-install scripts

Tags: .net, bash, ubuntu

I have some .Net sdks installed under `usr/share/dotnet` and I'm trying to install a new version using [dotnet-install.sh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install) on the same location like so:

```
dotnet-install.sh --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet --no-path
```

Even though I've already `chmod +x` the script, installation keeps logging permission denied issues.

```
dotnet-install: Note that the intended use of this script is for Continuous Integration (CI) scenarios, where:
dotnet-install: - The SDK needs to be installed without user interaction and without admin rights.
dotnet-install: - The SDK installation doesn't need to persist across multiple CI runs.
dotnet-install: To set up a development environment or to run apps, use installers rather than this script. Visit https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download to get the installer.

dotnet-install: Attempting to download using primary link https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.101/dotnet-sdk-6.0.101-linux-x64.tar.gz
dotnet-install: Extracting zip from https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.101/dotnet-sdk-6.0.101-linux-x64.tar.gz
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/6.0.1/': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.0/': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.linux-x64/6.0.1/': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/6.0.1/': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/DotnetTools/dotnet-dev-certs/6.0.1-servicing.21567.14/': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/DotnetTools/dotnet-user-secrets/6.0.1-servicing.21567.14/': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/DotnetTools/dotnet-watch/6.0.101-servicing.21569.16/': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests/6.0.100/': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.1/': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/usr/share/dotnet/templates/6.0.1/': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/share/dotnet/LICENSE.txt': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/share/dotnet/ThirdPartyNotices.txt': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet': Permission denied
dotnet_install: Error: Failed to verify the version of installed `.NET Core SDK
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running the dotnet-install.sh script with sudo.
Or marking the dotnet-install.sh as executable: `sudo chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh`.